# Excel - Index Match using the Left property

Tags: excel

newbie here!
After scouring the web, can't quite find an exact answer:

I have two tabs in an excel sheet, one with master of information (PARAM), one is a template that gets copied (TEMPLATE). I need to index items from column A:A of Master tab if the two first characters are equal to $E$6 on the Template tab. The results go to Template tab A14 and downwards.

Not working, I'm assuming because I'm referencing the same column multiple times... I'm not catching something in the logic behind what I need in my formula.

Current formula :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PARAM!A:A, MATCH(IF(LEFT($E$6, 2)=LEFT(PARAM!A:A, 2), PARAM!A:A))), "")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=iferror(index(param!a:a, aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/(left($e$6, 2)=left(param!a$1:a$999, 2)), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

Fill down for 1101, 1102, etc. The remaining information can now be retrieved with basic VLOOKUP.

Comment: This works great! Since the Aggregate - Options - 6 is there, do I need to have iferror anyways?

Comment: I figured it out, returns a Value error without it. Keeping the IfError

Comment: seeing as the information in PARAM sheet is updated regularly and contains empty lines, the PARAM!a$1:a$999 range would automatically change and contain only the first lines until an empty one. I corrected the formula hence, and it works regardless of how times the cells are updated: =iferror(index(param!a:a, aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/(left($e$6, 2)=left(**param!$a:$a, 2**)), row(1:1))), text(,))

Answer (score 0):

Match allows the use of WildCards:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PARAM!A:A, MATCH(LEFT($E$6, 2)& "*", PARAM!A:A,0)), "")
```